# How to get data from an OPC server into my iPhone Xcode project?

Tags: xcode9, opc-ua

How to get data from an OPC server into my iPhone Xcode project? I have an OPC server and I want to communicate with it to send and receive data from it. I really have no idea where to start.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that Unified Automation's C++ SDK does mention XCode support in this [document](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/platform-support.html)

While *not* for Xcode, I have had success with these SDK's that use [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/platform) to build apps that run on iOS and Android.

https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard

https://github.com/convertersystems/opc-ua-samples

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to find an OPC UA Client SDK that is compatible with iOS.